# Deploying ASP.NET app on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have a ASP.NET web app (.NET 3.5 SP 1) compiled on a Windows XP x86 (32 bit) box. The app currently runs on a Windows 2003 (IIS 6) server. I'm planning to move the application to a Windows 2008 R2 (64 bit) server. I was wondering if anyone has had any experiences with a similar migration? Does a x86 ASP.NET web app work out-of-the-box on Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5)?

Cheers :)

Rowan

Comment: Surely you have a test x64 machine ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make the transition with minimal work.  We did it before.  We can talk offlist if you'd like, lemme know.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Please drop me an email. My email address can be found at http://www.emailcover.com/cJF.png

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have too many problems - we build and develop on XP x86/IIS 5.1 and deploy to a 64-bit Server 2008/IIS 7 platform. Just make sure you've got a staging environment to test on (even if it's just a Windows 7 installation for IIS 7).